# Iphone 3.0 More tab - not displaying when run in simulator

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have 5 views contained in my TabBarController, each view has a navigationController inside of it (Did this all through IB) and for some reason instead of the more tab displaying the 5th tab is shown. I have double-checked that all my nibs are declared and connections are created correctly in IB. In fact, all the views show when i click on the tab even the 5th. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Apple has apparently decided that 5 tabs is the most that should be visible at one time in the UITabBar.  If you have 5 or fewer, it just shows them all; thus the MORE tab is not needed, and will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got it,pretty strange..as soon as i put a sixth view controller under the tabbarcontroller the more tab shows up.Weird...

Answer (score 0):

could have sworn that in the latest docs it still says more than 4...maybe I misread something...